# twitter bootstrap carousel image centering

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I just started using twitter bootstrap and the carousel is behaving weirdly. I think it is related to the responsive design but i'm not sure. On fullscreen the image is not centered. When the window gets smaller it resizes perfectly.

fullscreen:
[image: wide]

Smaller:
[image: short]

All of the code is a straight bootstrap download. http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out right after typing the question. The image resizes perfectly with a width of 1500PX. I guess that is the width of the container?